# Which compiler to use to compile java, aspectj, and groovy files in Intellij Idea?

Tags: groovy-eclipse

I have a multi module project. There are java, aspects on aspectj and groovy. My problem is incorrect compilation of all this files together. If I choose  **Ajc** compiler it can't compile groovy, if I choose **Groovy-Eclipse** compiler it can't compile aspects. How to solve this problem? Is there a compiler which can do all of them in one?